# What is the difference between Apache Spark and Apache Arrow?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-arrow, bigdata

What are the differences between Apache Arrow and Apache Spark?
Will Apache Arrow replace Hadoop?

Answer (score 5):

- **Apache Arrow** is a *proposed* in-memory data layer designed to back different analytical loads.
- **Apache Spark** is a storage agnostic cluster computing framework.

These two don't belong to the same category and don't compete with each other same as Arrow doesn't compete with Hadoop.